# How to convert all elements of a bash array to lowercase?

Tags: arrays, bash, lowercase

I have an array in bash.

```
WHITELIST=(
   "THIS"
   "examPle"
   "somTHing"
)
```

How can I convert all elements to lowercase in the existing or in a new array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert the whole array in one shot:

```
WHITELIST=( "${WHITELIST[@],,}" )
printf "%s\n" "${WHITELIST[@]}"
```

```
this
example
somthing
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `${parameter,,}`:

```
WHITELIST=(
        "THIS"
        "examPle"
        "somTHing"
        )

i=0
for elt in "${WHITELIST[@]}"
do
    NEWLIST[$i]=${elt,,}
    i=$((${i} + 1))
done

for elt in "${NEWLIST[@]}"
do
    echo $elt
done
```

From the manpage:

> ```
>   ${parameter,,pattern}
>           Case  modification.   This expansion modifies the case of alpha‐
>           betic characters in parameter.  The pattern is expanded to  pro‐
>           duce  a  pattern  just as in pathname expansion.  The ^ operator
>           converts lowercase letters matching pattern to uppercase; the  ,
>           operator  converts matching uppercase letters to lowercase.  The
>           ^^ and ,, expansions  convert  each  matched  character  in  the
>           expanded  value;  the  ^ and , expansions match and convert only
>           the first character in the expanded value.  If pattern is  omit‐
>           ted,  it is treated like a ?, which matches every character.  If
>           parameter is @ or *, the case modification operation is  applied
>           to  each  positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the
>           resultant list.  If parameter is an array  variable  subscripted
>           with  @ or *, the case modification operation is applied to each
>           member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the  resultant
>           list.
> ```

Comment: Good solution but is `bash 4.x` only.

Comment: *shrug* and?  :)  `tr` (your answer) is a great fallback.

Comment: Dont get me wrong, I just thought it would be good to let OP know that to prevent unnecessary heartache of not able to execute a really good solution. :)

Comment: I had no idea about the feature until today.  I read the question, figured there would be a language feature to do it, and fired up the manpage and there it was.  I assumed it had been around forever, so it's a great heads up that it's only recent.

Comment: You should be using `for elt in "${WHITELIST[@]}"` (with the quotes and `@`) -- that's the only safe way to preserve elements containing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
$ WHITELIST=("THIS" "examPle" "somTHing")
$ x=0;while [ ${x} -lt ${#WHITELIST[*]} ]
    do WHITELIST[$x]=$(tr [A-Z] [a-z] <<< ${WHITELIST[$x]})
    let x++
done
$ echo "${WHITELIST[@]}"
this example somthing
```

Comment: The loopless variety may change the number of elements in `WHITELIST`, subject to word splitting.

Comment: @chepner You are right!! If you don't mind, can you please explain why that happened?

Comment: `tr` reads the input as a single string of text, losing any notion of where one element stops and the next begins. The output is likewise a single string of text, which the shell splits into words based on the current value of `IFS` to set the new value of `WHITELIST`. In short, `tr` doesn't know about arrays, and so cannot preserve the distinction between elements.

Comment: Thanks so much @chepner. Appreciate the explanation.